# Graph API/FQL website page impressions

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

Is there a way to query Graph/FQL for insights type data for pages on my own website?

This data exists in the FB user interface for Facebook Insights, and I can look at page level impression data for pages on my website, but it's not clear if it's available anywhere programmatically.

Comment: Has anyone else had any experience with this?